# How to deploy a tagged branch from GitHub with the 'Deploy to Heroku' Button

Tags: heroku, github

I know I can use the ['Deploy to Heroku' Button](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button) to deploy an application stored at GitHub with the link:

`https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/myorg/myproject`

and if I want to deploy a certain branch I can use:

`https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/myorg/myproject/tree/master`

What I somehow can't get working is to deploy a tagged release. A deploy button with the link to the release with the tag to e.g. v1.1.1 like

`https://heroku.com/deploy?template=https://github.com/myorg/myproject/releases/tag/v1.1.1`

just deploys the current master branch. Does anyone know how to deploy a tagged branch from GitHub?

Comment: Does https://github.com/myorg/myproject/tree/v1.1.1 not work?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it.